# Date export from Matlab to excel

Tags: excel, matlab

i have a set of data for couple of days and the names of the data files like this

```
name='Newyork20200915'
```

which is for the 15th of September and i want to export only the date to excel like shown below

[image]

So how can i get the date from the name string ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the other part of `name` will not contain any digits besides the date, you can use `regexp` to get all the digits from the character array:

```
name = 'Newyork20200915'
date_only = regexp(name, '\d*', 'match')
```

Next, you can convert this date string to a serial date number using `datenum`, by providing the format in which the date is currently. And then use `datestr` to format it to your desired format.

```
date_formatted = datestr(datenum(date_only, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd. mmm')

date_formatted =

    '15. Sep'
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but when i export it to excel i want it in the same cell, but what happens that every cell takes a digit of , im using this comman 
>> xlswrite('trial.xls',date_formatted,'A1), do you have any idea? btw the anwer is accepted and upvoted

Comment: You should put the contents you want to write to excel in a cell array, [see the docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html#btmdr27-1-A)